# VS2013 .NET 4.5 ASP.NET ADFS Get UPN out of Claims

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, wif, adfs

How do I get User Principal Name (UPN) out of the claims from an ASP.NET site using ADFS for authentication? I am suppose to be getting back the display name and the UPN but all I am able to see is the display name.

This is how I am getting the current display name.

User.Identity.Name

But looking through the user and Identity objects it is not clear where the UPN is located.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to work...

First I found this post: https://syfuhs.net/2010/09/09/converting-claims-to-windows-tokens-and-user-impersonation/

This helped a lot but I had to convert it from WIF 3.5 to 4.5.  This is what I have in the end.

Import statements:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Security.Claims
```

Snippet of code to use:

```
Dim identity As ClaimsIdentity = DirectCast(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity, ClaimsIdentity)
Dim upn As String = identity.Claims.Where(Function(c) c.Type = ClaimTypes.Upn).First().Value

If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(upn) Then
    Throw New Exception("No UPN claim found")
End If
```

Hope this helps someone else!